# Bind Boolean values as "yes "no" in datagrid text column in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I need to show 0 and 1 Boolean values as YES and NO inside the data grid cell.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Active" Binding="{Binding stuen.IsDelete}" CanUserResize="False" Width="* "  HeaderStringFormat="" >
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"  Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace the `DataGridTextColumn` with a `DataGridTemplateColumn`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Active" CanUserResize="False" Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="NO" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding stuen.IsDelete}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="YES" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 7):

Simple enough - You can extend status model with additional property (say YesNo) like :

```
public string YesNo
{
   get {return !IsDelete ? "No" : "Yes"}
}
```

and now bind your control with status.YesNo rather than status.IsDelete.

**Alternatively** - You can use `BooleanToYesNoConverter` in your binding element. Basically converter would return Yes for status.IsDelete = true and No for status.IsDelete=false.

Like :

```
public class BooleanToYesNoConverter : IValueConverter
        {
                public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
                {
                        if((bool)value) return "Yes";
                         return "No"
                }

                public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
                {
                        return null;
                        /* not sure if you need convert back */
                }
        }
```

Add this converter as a static resource in your Xaml :

```
<Window.Resources>
                <local:BooleanToYesNoConverter  x:Key="BooleanToYesNoConverter" />
        </Window.Resources>
```

Then update your binding attribute to :

```
Binding="{Binding stuen.IsDelete Converter={StaticResource BooleanToYesNoConverter}}"
```

**Other Alternative solution would be to use trigger like below :**

```
<TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding status.IsDelete}" Value="Yes">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="No" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
```

Comment: It is not working.I found the source website that you have copied these things. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: yup, i updated last alternative solution from other forum.

Comment: There seems to be a missing comma in the binding expression, i.e. `Binding="{Binding stuen.IsDelete, Converter [...]`